# dojox.charting axis labels dropping

Tags: javascript, charts, dojox.charting

Using dojox.charting to create a column chart. The x-axis labels are dates, and only one label seems to print if the number of series is 10 or more, even though `dropLabels: false` is being used.

When I tweak the loop to stop at 9 iterations, it prints all the labels just fine. As soon as it hits 10 items, only one label will print. I even tried shortening the label length in case that did something, but the same thing happened.

Anyone know why this would happen? Is it a bug or are we just doing something wrong?

**Edit:** 
I discovered something interesting. It's not just that only one label prints if you're at 10 or more iterations. *Only* the **10th** label prints.

[image: 9 items]

[image: 10 items]

[image: 16 items]

Here's how the chart object is being instantiated. If more detail would be helpful, I can provide it.

```
chart = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("lineChartDiv");
chart.addPlot("default", { type: "ClusteredColumns", label: true, labelStyle: "outside", labeloffset: 5, gap: 15, minBarSize: 15, maxBarSize: 15, enableCache: true });
chart.addPlot("other2", { type: "Columns", gap: 30, minBarSize: 50, maxBarSize: 50, stroke: { color: "rgba(0,0,0,.3)" }, fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", enableCache: true });
chart.addPlot("other3", { type: "Columns", gap: 30, minBarSize: 50, maxBarSize: 50, stroke: { color: "rgba(0,0,0,1)" }, fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", enableCache: true });
chart.addPlot("other", { type: "Grid", hMajorLines: true, hMinorLines: false, vMajorLines: false, vMinorLines: false, majorHLine: { color: "rgba(0,0,0,.3)", width: 1 }, renderOnAxis: false, enableCache: true });


console.log('labels', labels);
chart.addAxis("x", { labels: labels, stroke: "#a6a6a6", majorTicks: true, minorTicks: false, minorLabels: false, dropLabels: false });
chart.addAxis("y", { vertical: true, stroke: "#a6a6a6", majorTickStep: EachTickStep, minorTicks: false });
chart.addSeries("Actual Burnup Past", actualBurnupPast, { stroke: { color: "#00b7e2" }, fill: "#00b7e2" });
chart.addSeries("Planned Burnup", plannedBurnup, { stroke: { color: "#a6a6a6" }, fill: "#a6a6a6" });
chart.addSeries("Hardening", hardening, { plot: "other2" });
chart.addSeries("Regression", regression, { plot: "other3" });

chart.render();
```

Comment: You can try to examine generated SVG by using developer tools, maybe these labels exist, but hidden. Also create an example in jsfiddle.net if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After inspecting the output, the labels do *not* exist. There is only the one that is visible in the picture. When I changed it to only do 9 iterations, I can find all the labels. So it's not that the HTML output has the <div>s and they're hidden, there's just one being generated, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was related to the property `majorTickStep`. If it's not defined, it seems to be defaulting to 10 if there are 10 or more series being displayed. When I explicitly set the value, then the labels print as expected.

```
majorTickStep: 1
```

Comment: It seems ridiculous, that although this is technically in the [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/charting.html), it is totally ambiguous what this attribute does. As a general question, is there a way to improve the documentation for Dojo?